# Export data (offline): save and share a file

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugin-file

I would like to offer a convenient way to backup data from my Cordova app to the users. The most appealing to me is that my app would backup all data into a JSON file and then offer the user to save/share it same way as any other file.

I've got as far as saving the data into a real file and invoking the share dialog, but the file fails to share/save. It's probably because external apps don't have permissions to access the file created by my app (GMail says: 'Permission denied for the attachement') and I don't know how to allow the external apps to access the file created by my app. Any ideas?

My code:

```
ex = JSON.stringify(ex);

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL('cdvfile://localhost/temporary/', function(dir)
{
    console.log('Directory resolved.');

    dir.getFile('MakeShift.json', {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(file)
    {
        console.log('Date file created.');

        file.createWriter(function (fileWriter)
        {
            fileWriter.onwriteend = function()
            {
                console.log('Data saved.');

                var time = Date.now();

                console.log(file); // typeof FileEntry

                window.plugins.socialsharing.shareWithOptions({
                    message: 'My MakeShift backup from '+time,
                    subject: 'MakeShift Backup '+time.yyyymmdd(),
                    files: [file.nativeURL],
                    chooserTitle: 'Choose how to save your data'
                },
                function(result)
                {
                    file.remove(function (file)
                    {
                        console.log('Data file removed.');
                    });
                });
            };

            fileWriter.onerror = function(e)
            {
                console.log('There was an error writing the data file.', e);
            };

            fileWriter.write(new Blob([ex], { type: 'application/json' }));
        });
    },
    function(err)
    {
        console.log('There was an error creating the data file.', err);
    });
});
```